# Gitlab Shell Executor Runner nodejs- command not found

Tags: node.js, devops, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have an angular8 project and trying to use the Gitlab shell runner.

Gitlab-CI should build and then stop existing docker container and spawn a new one.

In my host, I have installed docker and Node(using mvn). When the runner executes, I am getting **command not found**.

Following is my code:

**gitlab-ci.yml**

```
stages:
 - build-vf
 - deploy-vf

build-min-code-vf:
  stage: build-vf
  tags:
    - branch/angular8/VF
  only:
    - branch/angular8/VF
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist/testprofilefrontend-app/
  before_script:
   - export PATH=$PATH
 script:
   - node -v
   - npm install
   - ng build --prod
deploy-production:
  stage: deploy-vf
  tags:
   - branch/angular8/VF
  only:
   - migration/angular8/VF
  before_script:
   - export PATH=$PATH
 script:
   - dockerAll=$(docker ps -a --filter="name=VF-FRONTEND" -q | xargs)
   - dockerImage=$(docker images | grep "<image_name>")

   - if [ ! -z "$dockerAll" ]; 
     then
      docker rm $dockerAll -f &&
      docker image build -t <image_name> . && 
      docker container run -d -v <dir_name> -p 8082:8080 -- name <name> <image_name> && 
      docker push <image>;

     else
      docker image build -t <image_name> . && 
      docker container run -d -v <dir_name>  -p 8082:8080 --name <name> <image_name> && 
      docker push <image_name>;
    fi;
```

**Docker path**

```
/usr/bin/docker
```

**$PATH**

```
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
```

My assumption is that the runner is checking only /usr/local?

Unfortunately, I could not find any resources related to my case on google. I am quite new with CI/CD knowledge and would appreciate your help.

Thanks.